# How to get the text from radio button in a radio group when radio button checked state is changed

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I have created two radio buttons in a radio group dynamically and one of them is checked.
I need when i cheked another button then its value should be saved in string.
But i have implemented `checkedchangelistener` for this.But its not working first time.
Here is my code.

```
rg = ((RadioGroup)getActivity().findViewById(alist_id.get(i)));
rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rd, int checkedId) {
        for(int i=0; i<rd.getChildCount(); i++) {
            radio_button = (RadioButton) rd.getChildAt(i);
            int id = radio_button.getId();
            if(radio_button.getId() == checkedId) {
                text = radio_button.getText().toString();
                flag=true;
                System.out.println("trueeeeeeeee"+text);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
});
if (flag==true) {
    updated_list.add(text);
    System.out.println("sssssssssssssssssss");
}else {
    updated_list.add(data_from_list_view.get(i));
    System.out.println("falseeeeeee");
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioSex"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioMale"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio_male" 
        android:checked="true" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioFemale"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio_female" />

</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_display" />

</LinearLayout>
```

java code

```
package com.mkyong.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {
    private RadioGroup radioSexGroup;
    private RadioButton radioSexButton;
    private Button btnDisplay;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    addListenerOnButton();

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        radioSexGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
        btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);

        btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    // get selected radio button from radioGroup
                int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                // find the radiobutton by returned id
                    radioSexButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

                Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
                    radioSexButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there can be problem due to selected radio button?

Comment: For this answer, you must have to checked `RadioButton` Id by using attribute `android:checkedButton="@+id/radioMale"` in `RadioGroup`. If you will click on button directly then it may get error `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 6):

try following code

```
radiogroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            int id=group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            RadioButton rb=(RadioButton) findViewById(id);
                                     OR
            RadioButton rb=(RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);

            String radioText=rb.getText().toString();

        }
    });
```

Comment: I have created dynamically radio button as follow:-

Comment: final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[list_of_radiobutton_data.size()];
          rg = new RadioGroup(getActivity());
      rg.setId(i);
      rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
      for (int i1 = 0; i1 < list_of_radiobutton_data.size(); i1++) {
       rb[i1] = new RadioButton(getActivity());
       rb[i1].setText(list_of_radiobutton_data.get(i1));
       rb[i1].setId(i1);
       rg.addView(rb[i1]);
       if (rb[i1].getText().equals(data_from_list_view.get(i))) 
       {
        /*rb[i1].setChecked(true);*/
        rg.check(rb[i1].getId());
         }
      }

Answer (score 3):

try this...

```
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
            String text = radioButton.getText().toString();
            updated_list.add(text);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is this code is correct ? which changes i have to implement for calling first time checked change listener?

Comment: Radiogroup.checkedChangeListener is not calling first time.

Comment: code written in comments section is not readable. just edit your answer and write there...

Comment: final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[list_of_radiobutton_data.size()];
rg = new RadioGroup(getActivity());
      rg.setId(i);
      rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
      for (int i1 = 0; i1 < list_of_radiobutton_data.size(); i1++) {
       rb[i1] = new RadioButton(getActivity());
       rb[i1].setText(list_of_radiobutton_data.get(i1));
       rb[i1].setId(i1);
       rg.addView(rb[i1]);
if (rb[i1].getText().equals(data_from_list_view.get(i))) 
       {
        rb[i1].setChecked(true);
        /*rg.check(rb[i1].getId());*/
 }
}

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin code for retrieving text from a checked RadioButton in RadioGroup

```
    binding.genderRadiogroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, _ ->
        var id: Int = binding.genderRadiogroup.checkedRadioButtonId
        var rb: RadioButton = binding.genderRadiogroup.findViewById(id)
        Toast.makeText(this,rb.text.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution for retrieving the text:

```
radiogroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

     void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rg, int checkedId) {
          for (int i = 0; i < rg.getChildCount(); i++) {
               RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) rg.getChildAt(i);
               if (btn.getId() == checkedId) {
                   String text = btn.getText();
                   // do something with text
                   return;
               }
          }
     }
});
```

Comment: Is there can be problem due to selected radio button?

Comment: @amita Have you set `radiogroup.check(IdOfYourButton)`, coz in this case your radio button is selected by default so in that case listener will not get called the first time.

Comment: AndroidWarrior No, i haven't..At the time of creation i have to set ?

Comment: I am creating radio button dynamically by using this code
final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[list_of_radiobutton_data.size()];
          rg = new RadioGroup(getActivity());
      rg.setId(i);
      rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
      for (int i1 = 0; i1 < list_of_radiobutton_data.size(); i1++) {
       rb[i1] = new RadioButton(getActivity());
       rb[i1].setText(list_of_radiobutton_data.get(i1));
       rb[i1].setId(i1);
       rg.addView(rb[i1]);
       if (rb[i1].getText().equals(data_from_list_view.get(i))) 
       {
        rb[i1].setChecked(true);
         }
      }

Comment: Is this code is correct ? which changes i have to implement for calling first time checked change listener?

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin version for the getting text** from the RadioGroup in the Fragment be like:

```
private lateinit var genderRadioGroup: RadioGroup

genderRadioGroup = rootView.gender_radio_grp

val selectedRadioButton: Int = genderRadioGroup.checkedRadioButtonId
        radioButton = rootView.findViewById(selectedRadioButton)
        Toast.makeText(context, "Selected gender is ${radioButton.text}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

(P.S. I'm using Android Extension to get the reference of the view )

Answer (score 0):

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
            group.findViewById<AppCompatRadioButton>(checkedId)?.let { radioButton ->
                val textFromButtonLabel = radioButton.text.toString()
            }
        }
```