# ANDROID - how do I get text from radio button and insert it to sqlite database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, radio-button

I am trying to get the text from the radio button and insert in into my SQLite database. I cannot use

```
*selectedGender.getText().toString();
```

I normally code a simple insert query like this:

```
boolean isInserted = mydb.addguardian(
                        edtuname.getText().toString(),
                        edtpass.getText().toString());
```

This is my code for the insert query on my `DBHelper`. I removed the `selectedGender.getText().toString();` because it causes an error. What I am trying to get is the text from the radiobutton after it checks what the user has chosen.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138445/how-to-get-the-text-from-radio-button-in-a-radio-group-when-radio-button-checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to get your checked RadioButton.

You can do it on demand or listen to the change selection event and store the value for further use

**V1:**

```
int checkedButtonId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
RadioButton checkedButton = findViewById(checkedButtonId);
String ButtonText = checkedButton.getText().toString();
```

**V2:**

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    String text = ((RadioButton)findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();
        }
    });*
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you