# TextInputLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.RadioButton

Tags: android

I'm getting this exception here and i have no idea what's the problem here. I'm using radio-group and getting the value from checked radio-button.

```
deliveryScheduleRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
         int selection = deliveryScheduleRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

         if(selection != -1)
         {
             RadioButton selectedButton = findViewById(selection);
             selectedText = selectedButton.getText().toString();
         }}});
```

And get this exception here:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.RadioButton
    at com.perkssbazaar.member.view.Order.PaymentMenu$10$1.onCheckedChanged(PaymentMenu.java:747)
    at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:190)
    at android.widget.RadioGroup.access$600(RadioGroup.java:57)
    at android.widget.RadioGroup$CheckedStateTracker.onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup.java:375)
    at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:174)
    at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:127)
    at android.widget.RadioButton.toggle(RadioButton.java:76)
    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:132)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6587)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:784)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26125)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6715)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:911)
```

**Edit**

#### Here's the XML of RadioGroup

```
<RadioGroup                         
android:id="@+id/idOrderDeliverySlotsRadioGroup"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:buttonTint="@color/redColor"
android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_regular"
android:shadowColor="@color/headingColor"
android:text="Empty Slots"
android:textColor="@color/headingColor"
android:textSize="17dp"/>
```

#### Java Code

Data is coming from API.

```
for (int i = 0; i < deliverySlotsData.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject object = deliverySlotsData.getJSONObject(i);
                            RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(PaymentMenu.this);
                            radioButton.setButtonTintList(colorStateList);
                            if(!object.getString("OrderDeliveryPrice").equals("0"))
                                radioButton.setText(object.getString("OrderDeliverySlotTitle") + " - " + object.getString("OrderDeliveryPrice"));
                            else
                                radioButton.setText(object.getString("OrderDeliverySlotTitle"));

                            radioButton.setId(i);
                            deliveryScheduleRadioGroup.addView(radioButton);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

Thank so much.

Comment: Could you post the layout XML file for that particular activity/fragment?

Comment: let me edit the post with xml

Comment: Checkout this solution it fixed mine once. [RadioGroup.getChildAt(id)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20138475/11479936)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are having an issue where you have 2 views in your layout with the same id, so when you retrieve by view id, you are likely ending up with the first instance with the same id.

Instead of `setId(i)` on radioButton in your loop, you should try `generateViewId()`. This method should ensure you don't end up with clashing ids. [See documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId()).

Comment: Thanks. It was working fine with the setId(index) before this statement `RadioButton selectedButton = findViewById(selection);` end up crashing my application. All i want is the text from selected radio button

Comment: Your exception is a ClassCastException, which means the first view retrieved with the ID you are requesting is not a RadioButton. The first view it found with that id is a TextInputLayout. If you are properly saving the id, this means you have 2 views in your layout with the same ID.

Comment: If that doesn't fix it, then you have an issue in how your selected id is being stored within the RadioGroup (which seems unlikely).

In general, `generateViewId()` is better than explicitly setting a view id though, as it's guaranteed to make sure you won't have a conflicting id.

Answer (score 1):

You can use getChildAt(id) method. It will fixed your problem.

```
deliveryScheduleRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                            RadioButton selectedButton = (RadioButton) group.getChildAt(checkedId);
                            selectedText = selectedButton.getText().toString();
                            });
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this one.

Comment: Get child at will return the view in that specific position within the view. Passing an id into that is not a proper use of the function.

Comment: i tried and it fixed my problem. but generateViewId() is better.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code:

```
deliveryScheduleRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
         int selection = scheduleRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
...
```

You set the listener to **`deliveryScheduleRadioGroup`** but you are getting checked button id from **`scheduleRadioGroup`**.

You added your radio buttons to **`deliveryScheduleRadioGroup`** not `scheduleRadioGroup`:

```
 deliveryScheduleRadioGroup.addView(radioButton);
```

I don't know how this resulted in the error you are getting, it probably has something to do with the id being returned based on some other part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you are sending wrong ID for finding the views.

Comment: Can you elaborate further where exactly. My code was running fine before this statement `RadioButton selectedButton = findViewById(selection);`