# How to get text from checked radio button in a group

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the text from a selected radio button in a group. I have searched for the same issue and the solutions that I get still get me to the same error.

```
2021-08-07 11:14:14.464 7297-7297/com.findplaceslaxco.ecommerce W/System.err:     at com.findplaceslaxco.ecommerce.Adapters.SecondCartAdapter$ViewHolder$2$1.onCheckedChanged(SecondCartAdapter.java:276)
```

This is the code:

```
mRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        if (checkedId != -1){
            MaterialRadioButton radioButton = (MaterialRadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
            boolean isChecked = radioButton.isChecked();//this is where the error appears
        }

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Try Checking Out this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138445/how-to-get-the-text-from-radio-button-in-a-radio-group-when-radio-button-checked/20138928) link it will help You

Comment: Thank you guys for your responses, i came to find out that the group childrenCount is zero though still showing radioButtons.

Answer (score 0):

**find RadioButton by id and get text**

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
       {
           radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), radioButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   }
   );
```